# How to upgrade reaction roles in discord.js from v12 to v13?

Tags: discord.js

I am trying, in discord.js, to create a reaction roles system and the below code worked in v12 but now that I'm in v13 it's not working. When I react, it doesn't even console.log working. What is the difference I am failing to grasp? This is my client by the way "const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS], partials: [['MESSAGE', 'REACTION', 'CHANNEL']] });"

```
client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, member) => {
   if (reaction.message.id == 'id here') {
      console.log('working')
      const guild = reaction.message.guild;
      const memberWhoReacted = guild.members.cache.find(user => user.id === member.id);
      if (reaction.emoji.name === `⛰️`) {
         const role = guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Hiker');
         memberWhoReacted.roles.add(role);
      }
   }
})
```

Comment: Hey, I think this code should work. Can you move ```console.log('working')``` line to 2. line? (For understanding the exact error)

Comment: @SuleymanCelik I moved around the console.log and it didn't work anywhere, even directly after the messageReactionAdd so it doesn't seem to be registering that. It's weird though because I have other similar event triggers (like a member joining the server) that works just fine. I also have the same code with messageReactionRemove and that doesn't trigger either. Maybe it's an intents issue? Are those structured correctly?

Comment: Hello again, I posted an answer. I think it will be helpful :)

Comment: @SuleymanCelik I responded to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you **didn't** put `Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS,` to your **intents** on your **main file**. That's why it's **not working**.

**NOTE**: Don't add all intents to your bot.

Comment: I have added Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS to my intents row as I put in the original post. It may be a permissions issue but that part is already in.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Did you open your intents on [discord developer website](https://discord.com/developers/applications/)?

Comment: yes, all the checkboxes are enabled.

Comment: It's very weird. I couldn't find anything. Sorry :(

Comment: It's ok, thank you for trying! I'm just as puzzled